# reading binary file as utf-16 c

Tags: c, binary

I am very beginner in c and I read a binary file in the program and put the contents into a struct as follows:

```
Struct Student{
  char name [32];
  char surname [16];
  char gender;
  char email [32];
  char phone_number [16];
  char addres [32];
  char level_of_education [8];
 }
```

name field in file needs to be read utf-16. how can I do that without using library?

Comment: Look into the `fread` and `fwrite` functions.  Then make an attempt, and if you have problems come back with a *specific* question.

Comment: `char` is usually 8 bits wide, but UTF-16 code units are 16 bits wide (as the name suggests), so you will need to convert the data read from the file to a different character encoding - probably UTF-8.

Comment: "without using library" --> With no library call, there is no input from a file.  Ceritnaly the requirement about "without using library" is mistaken.   mojave,  Please explain.

Comment: I used stdio.h, string.h and stdlib.h of course I mentioned not using a special library for the utf-16 reading part.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+reading+utf -- your question is not totally uncommon.